# set FCM high-priority when using firebase-admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following code which uses firebase-admin to send messages using Firebase cloud messaging

```
Message message = null;
message = Message.builder().putData("From", fromTel).putData("To", toTel).putData("Text", text)
            .setToken(registrationToken).build();

String response = null;
try {
    response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get();
    responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

The above code works fine. But I need to send "high-priority" messages so that the device can receive them while in doze mode.

How can I make the messages "high-priority"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sending to Android devices, when building the message, set its [AndroidConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/AndroidConfig) to a value that has [Priority.HIGH](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/AndroidConfig.Priority):

```
AndroidConfig config = AndroidConfig.builder()
        .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH).build();

Message message = null;
message = Message.builder()
        .putData("From", fromTel).putData("To", toTel).putData("Text", text)
        .setAndroidConfig(config) // <= ADDED
        .setToken(registrationToken).build();
```

For additional details, see the [example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#android_specific_fields).

When sending to Apple devices, use `setApnsConfig()`, as explained in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#apns_specific_fields).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The high priority is working, but still if I don't touch my phone for a while, and when I send it a Firebase cloud message it takes the phone a very long time to process it. Am I supposed to using Firebase Job Dispatcher in order for my app to work when the phone is sleep? When the phone is awake the phone processes everything within a few seconds

Comment: With a  high-priority message, I would expect the message receipt delay  to be about the same for an awake and sleeping device.  What model phone are you testing with?  I have seen reports of different behaviors depending on device model.

Comment: It's running on the Moto G4 Play

Comment: You could try sending notifications from the Firebase Console.  The are high-priority by default and will give you an idea of receipt delay for different device states.

Comment: I did some debugging, I now print something on the app screen with a timestamp when a Firebase message is received. The message does appear, but it does not continue to do rest of the job. It's supposed to create a new instance of a class, then create a new thread and download an image. This is the class that it will use once a Firebase message is received https://pastebin.com/RUrZwb4L I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong on my side

Comment: SO is not an efficient forum for debugging.  I would expect an awakened device to remain awake for at least 10 seconds.  Maybe the image download is taking longer than expected.  You're making good use of log-statements.  Add more if needed to determine if the device is going to sleep before the processing is complete.

Comment: I will try to figure it out with more debugging, but I think the issue is the phone. I'm going to try it with a different ROM to see what happens

Answer (score 2):

```
public async Task send_PushNotification(FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message MESSAGE)
    {   
        var defaultApp = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "key_FB.json")),
        });

        var message = MESSAGE;
        message.Token = FB_TOKEN;
        message.Android = new AndroidConfig();
        message.Android.Priority = Priority.High;
        message.Android.TimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
       
        var messaging = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;
        var result = await messaging.SendAsync(message);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation to your answer, e.g. putting it in the context of a question.

Answer (score 2):

Without an AndroidConfig Builder

```
function sendFCM(token, from, to, text) {
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");
    var data = {
        from: from,
        to: to,
        text: text
    };
    let message = {       
        data: data,
        token: token,
        android: {
            priority: "high",  // Here goes priority
            ttl: 10 * 60 * 1000, // Time to live
        }
    };
    admin.messaging()
        .send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            // Do something with response
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help somebody.

```
public String sendFcmNotification(PushNotificationRequestDto notifyRequest) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
        String registrationToken = notifyRequest.getToken();

        AndroidConfig config = AndroidConfig.builder()
                .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH).build();

        Notification notification = Notification.builder()
                .setTitle(notifyRequest.getTitle())
                .setBody(notifyRequest.getBody())
                .build();

        Message message = Message.builder()
                .setNotification(notification)
//                .putData("foo", "bar")
                .setAndroidConfig(config)
                .setToken(registrationToken)
                .build();


        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
    }
```

Comment: Worked nicely! Thanks.